# Не работает prop на checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Выводит только False.

Это JS

```
  send__user.click(function(event){
      var check1 = $("#check1");
      if(check1.prop("checked") == "checked") { 
          alert("True");
          event.preventDefault();
      }
      else if(check1.prop("checked") != "checked"){
          alert("False");
          event.preventDefault();
      }
  })

});
```

Это HTML

```
<form action="file.php" method="post">
           <input type="checkbox" name="check1" class="check" id="check1" value="value4"> 
            <label id = "answer1">Answer 1</label> <br> <br>

           <button name="send" id="send__user">Send</button> 
           <br>  <br>
          
    <script src=my.js></script>
</div>
</form>
```

Если активировать checkbox и нажимать Send то должен сказать True но говорит False.

Comment: Всё замечательно. А теперь вам стоит добавить побольше подробностей в вопрос: что это за код? Что он должен делать? А что он не делает, хотя должен? В чём проблема и т.д.

Comment: Что где выводит? Что не работает? Хотя бы на словах опишите что не так...

Comment: ok------------------------------------

Comment: Ну..................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция prop("checked") не возвращает "checked", она возвращает true или false. Но лучше использовать is().

```js
$("#checkbox").click(function(){
  if($('#checkbox').is(':checked')){
    alert('On');
  }else{
    alert('Off');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
Click me
</label>
```